# FCM Android Notification sound issue

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notification using php to Android Application, and which is working fine without sound. I am receiving the notification both foreground and background as expected.

Here is the PHP code,

```
<?php


$token = $_GET['token'];
$action = $_GET['action'];
$msgTitle = $_GET['msgTitle'];
$msgDescription = $_GET['msgDescription'];
$notificationTitle = $_GET['notificationTitle'];


require './google-api-php-client-2.2.2/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials(); 
$client->setAuthConfig('./testPrjoectAPP-firebase-adminsdk-9hn21-22c1b3f426.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging');
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$project = "testPrjoectAPP";
$message = [
    "message" => [
        "notification" => [
            "body"  => "Message FCM",
            "title" => $notificationTitle
        ],
        "token" => $token,

       "data" => [
                "action" => $action,
            "msgTitle" => $msgTitle,
            "msgDescription" => $msgDescription 
         ]


    ]
];
$response = $httpClient->post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{$project}/messages:send", ['json' => $message]);
echo$response->getReasonPhrase(); // OK

?>
```

But when I add sound parameter to notification payload and execute php I am getting `Bad Request` error from php. 
.

```
$message = [
    "message" => [
        "notification" => [
            "body"  => "Message FCM",
            "title" => $notificationTitle,
            "sound" => "default"    
        ],
        // Send with token is not working
        "token" => $token,

       "data" => [
            "action" => $action,
            "msgTitle" => $msgTitle,
            "msgDescription" => $msgDescription
         ]


    ]
];
```

**Edit**

Here is the error message I got while printing with

```
data: "{\n \"error\": {\n \"code\": 400,\n \"message\": \"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \\\"sound\\\" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field.\",\n \"status\": \"INVALID_ARGUMENT\",\n \"details\": [\n {\n \"@type\": \"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest\",\n \"fieldViolations\": [\n {\n \"field\": \"message.notification\",\n \"description\": \"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \\\"sound\\\" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field.\"\n }\n ]\n }\n ]\n }\n}\n"
```

Comment: Please post error log.

Comment: May be you have to try it. : https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/458#issuecomment-365627529

I think you BIG BRACKET is problem as array. You may have to pass as Object as {} .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my comment, You have to use your JSON like following way.

Solution:
The appearance of message in your JSON indicates you are using the HTTP v1 API. The documentation you linked is for the legacy API.

The HTTP v1 API JSON to send a notification with sound for Android and iOS devices should be:

```
{
    "message":{
        "token":"your-token-value",
        "notification":{
            "title":"Test",
            "body":"Test message from server"
        },
        "android":{
            "notification":{
                "sound":"default"
            }
        },
        "apns":{
            "payload":{
                "sound":"default"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference Link is: [Unable to add sound to notification payload](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/458#issuecomment-365627529)

Thank you.

Comment: I had this exact structure using google-api-php-client and nothing was working..UNTIL.. I used double quotes instead of single quotes around "default" ...now it works,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    "message":{
        "token":"your-token-value",
        "notification":{
                "title":"Test",
                "body":"Test message from server"
        },
        "android":{
            "notification":{
                "sound":"default"
            }
        },
        "apns":{
            "payload":{
                "sound":"default"
            }
        }
    }
}
```