# Why Sound is not ringing when app is in background(Firebase Push Notification in Android app)?

Tags: android, firebase, audio, push-notification, android-notifications

When push notification is coming then sound and vibration working only when app is open. But when I kill my app or minimized it then only notification sound and vibrate coming if I send it from Firebase console. But if I am getting notification from php server then no sound and vibration.I have tired to many codes but same problem occur. And I have also tried in different Android os versions phone.

This is my code which I am using to create notification.

```
public void createNotification( String title, String message,Intent intent, Uri alarmSound) 
{
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel androidChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                title, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel should display notification lights
        androidChannel.enableLights(true);
        // Sets whether notification posted to this channel should vibrate.
        androidChannel.enableVibration(true);
        // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this channel
        androidChannel.setLightColor(R.color.app_theme_color);
        //androidChannel.setSound(null, null);

        // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel appear on the lockscreen or not
        androidChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        getManager().createNotificationChannel(androidChannel);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setTicker(title)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setSound(defaultUri)
                .setSound(alarmSound, STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        getManager().notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());

    } else {
        try {

            playNotificationSound();

            @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "LocalSuppress"}) NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.logo))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setTicker(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setSound(alarmSound, STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setLights(0xFF760193, 300, 1000)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{200, 400});


            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID/* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


private NotificationManager getManager() {
    if (mManager == null) {
        mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    return mManager;
}



// Playing notification sound
public void playNotificationSound() {
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And I have also given the permission in Manifest also.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

This is my php code.

```
public function pushSurveyorNotification($send_data){

    $requestJson = json_decode($send_data, true);

    if (empty($requestJson)) {
        generateServerResponse('0', '100');
    }

     $check_request_keys = array(
                '0' => 'message',
                '1' => 'regId',
                '2' => 'apikey',
                '3' => 'booking_details',
                '4' => 'notification_type'
            );

       // $notification_type  = '01';           
        $regId = trim($requestJson['Codruk']['regId']);
        $notification_type = trim($requestJson['Codruk']['notification_type']);
        $registrationId = ''; // set variable as array

        // get all ids in while loop and insert it into $regIDS array
        $deviceIds = explode(",", $regId);

        foreach ($deviceIds as  $devid) { 
            $registrationId .= $devid.",";
        }

        $message  = trim($requestJson['Codruk']['message']);            
        $apikey   = trim($requestJson['Codruk']['apikey']);
        $booking_details  = trim($requestJson['Codruk']['booking_details']);

        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send'; 

        $fields = array(
                        'to'  => rtrim($registrationId,","),

                        'notification' => array(
                                "title" => "Codruk",
                                "body"  => $message
                        ),
                        'data' => array(
                            "notification_type" => $notification_type,
                            "booking_details" =>json_decode($booking_details, true)
                        ),
                        'priority' => "high"
                    ); 

        $headers = array( 
                            'Authorization: key=' . $apikey,
                            'Content-Type: application/json'
                        );

       $data = json_encode( $fields );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending notification from firebase console and your app is in background onMessageReceived method will not be called inside MessagingService class.

Firebase will handle it at Backend.
It will send this Notification to system for displaying Notification in Notification tray.
And there will be no Notification sound even if you have enabled/allowed Notification sound for.

Basically, you need to change your notifiction code to something like this

```
{

 “to” : “bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1…”,

 “notification” : {

    “body” : “great match!”,

    “title” : “Portugal vs. Denmark”,

    “icon” : “myicon”,

    “sound” : “mySound”

    }
```

}

you can read more about how to do it here: [Firebase Cloud Messaging Push Notifications Android tutorial](http://developine.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notification-android-tutorial/)

Comment: please have a look at my question again. I am getting sounbd from FIrebase console but If I get notification from php server it will make sound only if app is open other wise no sound

Comment: I think you  forgot to add "sound" referral to your payload. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54090352/9233991)  out